# What happened when I join two different materials?

Tags: physics, materials

It is noob question cause I am noob, but if I have two different materials with different amount of electrons and I join them (just in hand if you know what I mean), why there is no electric current? They should try to balance the electrical potential or?

Comment: What kinds of materials are you talking about?  Are they dielectrics, or semiconductors, or metals?

Comment: You mean like your hand joining a door knob after walking across a carpet in socks?

Comment: Don't forget, that's how you make a thermocouple (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple).

Comment: I don't think it depends on the total number of electrons in each material, but rather the net charge of each material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no electric current because there is no potential pushing charges around one way or the other.  When you touch two conductors, such as metals, the electrons that can normally hop between atoms of each material can now hop between atoms between the materials.  As before, at the macro level no current flows because there is no potential that is pushing the electrons in any particular net direction.

Comment: Would it be better to clarify that there is no potential due to a lack of a difference in the net charge of each material? If one material is positively charged and the other is negatively charged, then because opposites attract and likes repel, this creates a force, or potential between them, correct? If each material has no charge, there is no potential energy, thus no possibility for charge to flow (regardless of the total number of electrons in each material). Sound right?

Comment: @Josh: If the two separate materials are initially at a different potential, then charge will flow for a short time to make the potential difference zero.  No charge will flow in stead state in either case.

Answer (score 7):

It's not about the number of electrons in a material, but about the number of *excess* or the *lack* of electrons in a material.

A negative charge is defined as an excess or electrons, and a positive charge as a dearth of electrons (or an excess of "holes" - the spaces where electrons *should* be).

Current flows when there are two materials with a difference in charges.  If you have a material with an excess of electrons and a material with a dearth of electrons (or an excess of holes) and they come into contact (or close enough for the insulating properties of air to be broken down) then the excess electrons in the first material will flow into the second material to fill the holes.

This is called "static electricity" because the initial charges are stationary (static) and contained within the materials until they come close enough for the electrons to flow.

In electronics we work with "active" electricity, which at the sub-atomic level is just the same as static electricity, except we use a power source to actively produce a difference in the number of electrons between two points in a circuit.

You can think of static electricity as a balloon full of air.  Burst the balloon and the air inside will rush out.  "Normal" electricity is like a fan - it's always trying to push the air through it.

Comment: so battery is producing those holes, where electrons should be?

Comment: Yes. The chemistry in the battery is grabbing the electrons from the + side and pushing them down to the - side.  The same with a generator - the magnetism is ripping the electrons out of their orbits around the atoms and shoving them all to one end.

Answer (score 1):

Solid materials are insulators, conductors or semiconductors. All are made of atoms that each have a positive charged nucleus and a number of electrons (negative charges). In normal "uncharged" material the total number of positive  charges equals the total number of negative charges.

An insulator's atoms hold their electrons tightly bound to the nucleus. Some electrons - the outer, 'valence' ones - can get closer to the positive nucleus when their they pair with others that belong to neighbouring atoms, and that results in an attraction or chemical bond that holds the atoms together as molecules and groups of molecules that usually bind together in a regular crystal formation. In an insulator all the electrons are tightly bound to their atoms, and it takes a lot of energy to release them and make them flow.

A conductor's atoms hold their outer electrons very loosely, and even small amounts of energy can loose them from the parent atom, so they continually break free and latch on to a nearby atom that has just lost an electron in the same way. In a good conductor the atoms are still bound to one another, but there are so many electrons in this loosely bound "conduction band" of energy that they behave like a fluid - imagine water flowing through a sponge. If nothing presses on the sponge or pours more water into it, the water is held. If you touched two wet sponges together there would be a small exchange of water between them, but no overall flow.

When you touch two pieces of metal together the situation is similar. *(However, different metals, or pieces of metal at different temperatures, do let electrons move more or less easily, in which case on the instant of contact there may be a  tiny and very short surge of current while some of the less-free electrons 'escape' into the easier surroundings. The slight excess of negative charge in the second piece opposes any further flow, and you can't measure a potential difference between the two, because any connection to a measuring device that completes a circuit between them also experiences the same effect on the opposing direction - unless the metal junctions are at different temperatures.)* Atoms in a conductor that lose an electron gain another practically immediately from a neighbour, so 'holes' don't persist in a good conductor.

Semiconductors are almost insulators, but have a limited number of loose electrons. It is more difficult for these to move than it would be in a good conductor, and a proportion of the atoms may be missing an electron at any given time, while spare electrons are loose and moving through the crystal structure. These 'holes' can transfer from atom to atom as each 'steals' an electron from its neighbour, so holes move in a similar way to electrons, and behave as if they were positively charged particles that can carry current.

When you apply a potential difference the source (battery) imposes a force on electrons that causes them to drift through the conductor and return to the lower potential side.